# Hyper-V Server 2016 setup empty screen

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I am trying to upgrade Hyper-V Server 2016 Core from Hyper-v Server 2012 R2, but when I run the setup wizard after "Making Sure you are ready to install" screen the next screen is empty.

Not sure what's going on here.[image]

After waiting for little longer I see that setup wizard is frozen, still not sure why. Tried on two different servers.

Comment: any reason for negative votes people? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: Can't comment, not enough rep: Duplicate/ same issue as: http://serverfault.com/questions/808941/upgrade-2012r2-core-to-2016-core-blank-window

Comment: @CSharpFan I guess this is Server Core install issue as I have successfully upgraded few machines (Server 2012 R2 to Server 2016) with Desktop UI.

Comment: It could be warning about: Microsoft NIC Teaming. NIC teaming (LBFO): Teams are not preserved during upgrade. Microsoft recommends deleteing all teams before the upgrade and recreating the teams after the upgrade is complete. For more info, refer to the Users' Guide at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

In my case I had to stop all the running VM's before starting the setup and that did the trick.